# jquery refresh div content (php function not file)

Tags: php, jquery

I need to refresh a div content every 1 second. The div contains of some php functions (not php files). What i have so far is not working.

**Update the quest:**
the php date function is just to test if ever 1 sec interval works. I do not want have the date time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
}, 1000);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"><?php echo date('H:i:s');?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You now only getting the innerHTML every second, you whant to create a clock?

Comment: You don't need php for that unless you you want to display server time. And even then you'll need to either use ajax or refresh the whole page to "call" the server and have php executed again

Comment: Whatever you try, you will not be able to update php content, unless you perform an AJAX request

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp I think you can better use a js function instead of asking the server every second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an AJAX call, in this case to the same file, however just targeting the `p` tag, `#demo`.

Let's say the name of the file is `time.php`, then the AJAX call would be:

```
$('#demo').load('time.php #demo');
```

This is all you need inside the `setInterval()` function and, the function would need either to be inside `$(function() { /*RIGHT HERE*/ });` or at the bottom of the file (right above the closing body tag) and, jQuery would need to be included.

**REF**

[.load() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/) - See § **Loading Page Fragments**